# Where can I find good references about the neuronal connections in various areas in the cortex?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroimaging, neurophysiology

As an example, I would like to know which Brodmann areas innervate the layer IV of area 10 in the brain.

To which degree are these connections known? What are good books or other kinds of resources that provide information about this, perhaps in a tabular form?

Comment: try shepherd: the synaptic organization of the brain.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I've skimmed a copy of it but I couldn't find what I am looking for since it is too specific. Just to get an idea of the state of art, is it at all possible to trace the connections to BA 10, layer IV via dissections or scanning methods?

Comment: yes, normally its done by injecting a retrograde tracer (rabies) into an area and seeing which areas express the fluorescent protein that the rabies virus was carrying

Comment: also check http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/334/is-there-a-complete-cortico-cortical-connectivity-map-based-on-a-useful-partitio?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. What I'm wondering about is this: In Ramnani & Owen (2004) and Petrides & Pandya  (2007) they note that BA 10 is very isolated from the sensory processing in the cortex, so it is conjectured that it is concerned with integrating result from other areas at a very high level. Yet, BA10 has a thin layer IV which is usually connected to the thalamus in other cortical areas. Hence, I'm wondering what it is connected to, if not to sensory circuitry.

Answer (score 2):

**[Diffusion tensor imaging](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2041910/)** (DTI for short) may be the technique you are after. It is able to record nerve fibers in MRI images. I couldn't find the specifics you were after,  and the subdivision into layers may outrun the resolution of MRI, but it may  be a good start. Two references that may get you going on tensor imaging are cited below. Additional, targeted [**electrophysiological**](http://www.acnp.org/g4/GN401000005/CH005.html) papers on  your area of interest may provide layer-specific connections.

<sub>**References**

**-** [Aggarwal *et  al*., *Neuroimage* (2015); **105**: 198–207](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4262592/)

**-** [Christoph  *et  al*., *Cereb Cortex* (2014); **24**(2): 328–39](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3888365/)</sub>